# www to non-www .htaccess not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

**EDIT**: The problem was that the domain was purchased at GoDaddy, but hosted at Endurance Internation Group (they own Hostgator and a few other small web hosts). Endurance doesn't have mod_rewrite activated by default, which is why this wasn't working.

I have hosted the site on GoDaddy and now everything works 100%.

---

I have a website that Google is indexing the www and non-www version of. I only want the non-www version. This is my current .htaccess code. The 301 redirects of individual files at the bottom work, but the www to non-www code at the top does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond % ^www.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect 301 /aboutcarytreeservice.html http://example.com/about.html
Redirect 301 /carytreeservice.html http://example.com/services.html
Redirect 301 /treeremovaldurhamnc.html http://example.com/durham.html
Redirect 301 /treeservicedurhamnc.html http://example.com/durham.html
Redirect 301 /treeremovalraleighnc.html http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition is wrong:

```
RewriteCond % ^www.example.com [NC]
```

change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: Comment out all `Redirect 301` lines and retest in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will look to see if there is a "www" in the URL and cause a 301 redirect to the same URL (with "www" added) if it is not.

Comment: Are you sure that you have mod_rewrite enabled on the server? Please check that.

Comment: Hi @user2036972, this is on a Linux server on GoDaddy which has mod_rewrite enabled by default. I am going to go in there and triple check, but I am 99.9% sure that is not the issue.